# In "go to sleep", is "to" a particle or a preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, particles

In the phrase *go to sleep*, I've always thought of *sleep* as a noun by analysis with *go to school*, which would make [*to*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to) a preposition. However, [*sleep*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleep) could possibly be interpreted as a verb, which would make *to* a particle.

Are both interpretations correct, or just one?

Comment: When Shakespeare wrote ['to sleep, perchance to dream'](https://www.owleyes.org/text/hamlet/read/act-iii-scene-i/root-71611-72/76460#root-71611-23) it seems to me that 'sleep' is definitely verbal and therefore 'to' is a particle. 'Go to sleep' can be more simply expressed, imperatively, as just 'Sleep !' which, again, is verbal. But 'go' is metaphorical, for one is not 'going' anywhere. So no preposition required. One is entering a state. I vote for particle, myself.

Comment: Why does it matter??

Comment: You're right: "sleep" is a noun here. Semantically, in the idiom "Go to sleep", "to sleep" is a 'state goal', but syntactically it is a locative complement, with "to" a preposition, and "sleep" an abstract noun as its complement (i.e. "to sleep" is a preposition phrase). Incidentally, 'particle' is not a word category (part of speech). Most so-called particles are prepositions occurring between verb and object as in "Kim took the suitcase _down_" ~ "Kim took _down_ the suitcase".

Comment: Of course sleep corresponds with school but so what? How does that help or change anything, please?

Answer (score 4):

This is a tricky question.

As strong evidence that at least some occurrences of "go to sleep" are using the preposition *to* and the noun *sleep*, I note that "[went right to sleep](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+right+to+sleep%22&tbm=bks)" is well-attested, which lines up with "[went right to school](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+right+to+school%22&tbm=bks)", "[went right to the heart of](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+right+to+the+heart+of%22&tbm=bks) the problem", and so on; whereas we don't say *"[went right to talk](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+right+to+talk%22&tbm=bks) to her", or *"[went right to see](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+right+to+see%22&tbm=bks) what was happening", or the like.

Another piece of evidence is the related idiom "[put <someone> to sleep](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+him+to+sleep%22&tbm=bks)"; *put* takes a prepositional phrase or the grammatical equivalent ("put <something> in the trash", "put <someone> outside", etc.), not an infinitive (*"[put <someone> to be](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+him+to+be%22&tbm=bks) <participle>", *"[put <someone> to talk](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+him+to+talk%22&tbm=bks) to her").

Conversely, I can't find any evidence that any occurrences are using the to-infinitive *to sleep*; I tried a few different kinds of searches:

- "went to <adverb> sleep" — I tried various adverbs, such as *[just](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+just+sleep%22&tbm=bks)*, *[quickly](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+quickly+sleep%22&tbm=bks)*, and *[merely](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+merely+sleep%22&tbm=bks)*, none of which were attested; however, corresponding searches with other verbs did not get many hits, either, so the lack of them for *sleep* is not a very compelling argument either way.
- "went to sleep <adverb-that-works-with-*sleep*> — all I could think of were *[deep](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+sleep+deep%22&tbm=bks)* and *[deeply](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+sleep+deeply%22&tbm=bks)*, neither of which is attested (whereas "[to sleep deep](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+sleep+deep%22&tbm=bks)" and "[to sleep deeply](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+sleep+deeply%22&tbm=bks)", without the "went", are both very well attested). I think this is a somewhat stronger piece of evidence, but of course I don't have any other clear-cut verb like *see* or *talk* to compare it to.
- "went to sleep <object>" — this is a very limited test, because almost the only objects that the verb *sleep* ever takes are noun phrases headed by the noun *sleep* (e.g. "to sleep the sleep of the just"); but for what it's worth, neither "[went to sleep a sleep […]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+sleep+a+sleep%22&tbm=bks)" nor "[went to sleep the sleep […]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22went+to+sleep+the+sleep%22&tbm=bks)" is attested.

So I would tentatively suggest that "go to sleep" only ever uses the preposition *to* and the noun *sleep*, even though in the vast majority of occurrences there's no way to definitively rule out the parse with the to-infinitive *to sleep*.

Answer (score 2):

***Sleep*** can be both a noun and a verb.  According to the OED when it is used, as it often is, in phrases with ***to*** "it is not always clear whether the noun or verb is intended".

Answer (score 0):

***Go to sleep*** (idiom) is an idiomatic expression, so *to* of it is not a preposition.

See [the MW dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20sleep) defines the idiom:

> 1: to begin sleeping
>
> *She lay down on the couch and went (right) to sleep.*
>
> *Tell the kids it's time to go to sleep.*
>
> *After the party, I just wanted to go to sleep.*
>
> 2: of a part of the body (such as a foot or leg) : to be without
>   feeling for a brief time usually because it has been kept in an
>   awkward position for too long.
>
> *When I started to get up I realized my foot had gone to sleep*

Note:  A few similar idiomatic expressions containing particle ***to*** are:

> [Go to church](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20church): to attend church services
>
> *They go to church every Sunday.*
>
> [Go to bed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20bed): to lie down in one's bed to sleep
>
> *She usually goes to bed around 11:00.*
>
> [Go to bat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20bat): (baseball) : to be the player or team that is batting.
>
> *The visiting team goes to bat first.*
>
> [Go to any length(s)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go%20to%20any%20length(s)): to make a great or extreme effort to do
>   something.
>
> *She'll go to any length(s) to avoid doing work.*

Comment: My understanding is that the particle goes with a verb, and the preposition goes with a noun. One of us has this backwards!

Comment: @CJDennis, ***Particle***, in connection with grammar, means *a word or a part of a word that has a grammatical purpose but often has little or no meaning*. In the sentence "I tidied up the room", the adverb "up" is a particle. {https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/particle}

Comment: Isn't it simpler all round to treat 'go to sleep' as a lexeme? Compare the verb 'awaken' (used intransitively). // 'Flatter to deceive' admittedly has me beat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: A lexeme can be a single word. Then, can an idiom be so?

Comment: [The way the first person to use the word, the renowned  grammarian David Crystal, defined it, 'kick the bucket' is a single lexeme when used metaphorically.](http://www.davidcrystal.com/?id=3535)

Comment: Yes – Crystal is a great linguist.

Comment: "Go to sleep" is not a lexeme, but an idiom. Crystal's opinion is entirely at odds with that of the widely accepted definition of lexeme, i.e. a unit corresponding to a word seen abstractly enough to include all of its inflectional forms, e.g. "take", takes, took, taken, and taken are the forms of the lexeme "take". "Go to sleep" is not a lexeme, but a clause with an idiomatic meaning, where "to sleep" is not a VP but an PP headed by the preposition "to".

Comment: @BillJ As per you explanation, *go* is a verb, *to* a preposition and *sleep* an object of the preposition. Then how it (an idiom) is different from a normal verb phrase such as *go to work* or *go to market*,etc.?

Comment: Further @BillJ, Does *go* of those idiomatic expressions have the normal dictionary meaning of *moving from one place to another*? I mean , does it mean a person physically travelling to another place to sleep?

Comment: It's an idiom because **syntactically** "to sleep" is a locative complement of the verb "go", but "sleep" is an abstract noun, not an actual place, as "market" is in "Go to market".  Semantically, "to sleep" is a state goal.

Comment: @BillJ  Yes, that's the reason, I think,  in an idiom nothing is normally taken as a concrete fact. Even in the idiom *go to church*, church is not taken as a concrete place, whereas it as an abstract idea (of prayer/praying). Idioms are based on abstract ideas, rather than individual word meanings. So, I believe, *go* doesn't have its individual word meaning and *to*is never a preposition.

Comment: No, "to" is preposition because syntactically "to sleep" is a PP functioning as a locative complement, as I have already explained.

Comment: @BillJ I'd welcome an answer from you.

Answer (score 0):

> *Go [to sleep].*

You're right: it's an idiom where "sleep" is not a verb but a noun.

Semantically, the bracketed element is a state goal, but syntactically it is a locative complement, with "to" a preposition, and "sleep" an abstract noun as its complement, i.e. "to sleep" is not a verb phrase but a preposition phrase.

Comment: This seems quite possible, but this answer would be much stronger if it provided some evidence for the claim.

Comment: @BillJ As per your answer, the idiom *go to sleep* is a semantic composition having a verb *go* and an object (a prepositional phrase). Then, would you say that *go* of the idioms *go to sleep, go to bed, go to church* has its primary meaning *move from one place to another* - especially when *bed* and *church* are concrete nouns? Please comment on the semantic role of *go* as well.

Comment: @mahmudkoya I think I answered that point yesterday.